# Counting consecutive fails in test results in Power BI

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I have a table containing test results.

The test results contain Buildnr, TestCase name and TestCase results.

[image: test results]

I want to create a new measure or a new column which calculates how many times a testcase has failed in a row.

e.g if i specify Build and TestCase it should show that the Test Case has failed x times in a row.

Build 125

TC_1 -> 3 fails in a row

TC_2 -> 2 fails in a row

TC_3 -> first failure

TC_4 -> No fails

One solutions would be to create a new table where which contains a matrix where the columns are TestCase names and The Rows Build_nr.  But i do not know how to do that.

What is the prefered way to find consecutive failures?

Comment: I realized I have an error in the script, it will count all . I need to go now, can look at it tommorrow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an extra column for you which counts the previous results.

```
ResultCount = 
var rowPickup = CALCULATE(MAX(TestCases[Build]);
    FILTER(TestCases;
        TestCases[TestCase] = EARLIER(TestCases[TestCase]) 
        && TestCases[Build] < EARLIER(TestCases[Build]) 
        && TestCases[Result] <> EARLIER(TestCases[Result])))
return 
    IF(rowPickup = BLANK(); 
        COUNTROWS(FILTER(TestCases; 
            TestCases[TestCase] = EARLIER(TestCases[TestCase]) 
            && TestCases[Build] < EARLIER(TestCases[Build]))) + 1 ; 
        TestCases[Build] - rowPickup)
```

end result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My resultcount does not seem to be set to 1 when going from Pass to fail or vice versa. [Table](https://imgur.com/NnUa6AG)

The column is calculated with:
result count = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Bundles),
FILTER(Bundles,Bundles[Bundle_nr] = EARLIER(Bundles[Bundle_nr])
&& Bundles[BuildNumber] < EARLIER(Bundles[BuildNumber])
&& Bundles[Passed] = EARLIER(Bundles[Passed]))) + 1

[Image of column calculation due to bad formatting](https://imgur.com/NfaJOnE)

Comment: You are correct, I made a mistake by going back all the way. I corrected this by taking the highest build number where the change happened and using this in the calculation for the times the test passed/failed.